# jQuery Accordion active by url?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, accordion

Header script section.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var show_link = '/hr/resitration'; // That is current url.
    var accordion = $("#accordion");
    active = ???? // How to found activ url???
    accordion.accordion({
        header: "h3",
        active: active,
        autoHeight: false
    });
});
```

in HTML section

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Dashboard</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/dashboard/my" >My works</a></li>
            <li><a href="/dashboard/send" >Send works</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">HR</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/hr/resitration?add=true" >Add Staff</a></li>
            <li><a href="/hr/resitration" >Staff list</a></li>
            <li>Config
                <ul>
                <li><a href="/hr/schools" >Schools</a></li>
                <li><a href="/hr/role" >Roles</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will get you close:

```
active = accordion.find("a[href="+show_link+"]").parents("h3");
```

Comment: active = accordion.find("a[href="+show_link+"]").parents("div").prev(); // That is worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I had to set `collapsible: true` and `navigation: true`, then `active = accordion.find("a[href="+show_link+"]").parents("div").prev();` worked for me as well.

Comment: @ewernli, I think the `.prev()` is the trick here since you can't select the `div`.  Don't you need to get the index of that `h3` though?

Answer (score 1):

```
var links =  accordion.find("a");
active = links.find("[href=/hr/resitration]").index();
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery UI 1.12, you need to supply the index of the `<h3>` separate from the `<div>`'s that contain the content in the accordion menus.  If you supply the index of the `<div>`, it will not work as you expect.

To achieve this, first find the nearest `<h3>` based on either the `window.location.href` or the `window.location.pathname`.  This matching depends on your anchor tag's URL and the URL of the page you are on.  We match the anchor tag first, then go up to the closest `<div>` and traverse one sibling back to the `<h3>` via:

```
$( "#accordion" ).find("a[href=\""+window.location.pathname+"\"]").closest("div").prev())
```

Then by selecting all H3s in your accordion menu:

```
$( "#accordion h3" )
```

We can get the index of the `<h3>` within this group of all `<h3>`s by combining this into one command via:

```
var active = $("#accordion h3").index($( "#accordion" ).find("a[href=\""+window.location.pathname+"\"]").closest("div").prev())
```

Then you can use this active index when you initialize your accordion, like so:

```
accordion.accordion({
    header: "h3",
    active: active,
    autoHeight: false
});
```